# Unsupported ZIP Compression method NaN Excel uploading

Tags: reactjs, excel, file-upload, zip

When uploading an Excel file (xslx) in React/e2e Playwright, I sometimes get "Unsupported ZIP Compression method NaN". How to handle such an error?

I tested it before but it worked. But apparently after that, or I thought it worked it got corrupt.

I thought it was a mimetype problem which was why I couldn't find anything online. I was working on e2e testing with Playwright.

If anyone else got the problem try clicking on your Excel file and if you see this just replace the file:
[Excel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk4lQ.png)

There is not a single post on this therefore this post. Hopefully it will help some people.

What I tried was using all different sorts of the same meaning:
await page.locator('#inputFile').setInputFiles(resolve(__dirname, 'test-file.xlsx'))

With click, without click, try buffer, etc.

Expected value just reads Excel file like it normally should.

Comment: It appears (to me, at least) that you are attempting to write a question and answer it. I suggest that you rephrase your question in order to make it an actual question, for example: _When uploading an Excel file (xslx) in React/e2e Playwright, I sometimes get "Unsupported ZIP Compression method NaN". How to handle such an error?_ Then you can post an answer. Refer to: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). In fact, I recommend that you take the [tour].